# How to change floating div's width to fill all the space they occupy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are six equal divs presented on a first picture. When a screen size increasing divs width becomes bigger in order the divs to fill all their place (table cell or another div). But if there are enough space to place fourth div in a first row it becomes so (second picture). After this a width of divs becomes initial (as in the first picture).
It is necessary for two divs in the second row to be centered.

Is it possible to solve the task with help of html+css only? Or only with help of javaScript. How to do this? Thanks you for any help.

First picture:

```
* * * *   * * * *   * * * *
*     *   *     *   *     *
*     *   *     *   *     *
* * * *   * * * *   * * * *

* * * *   * * * *   * * * *
*     *   *     *   *     *
*     *   *     *   *     *
* * * *   * * * *   * * * *
```

Second picture:

```
* * * *   * * * *   * * * *  * * * *
*     *   *     *   *     *  *     *
*     *   *     *   *     *  *     *
* * * *   * * * *   * * * *  * * * *

          * * * *   * * * *
          *     *   *     *
          *     *   *     *
          * * * *   * * * *
```

index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<div class="clearfix">                          
    <div class="outer-div">
        <div class="inner-div">
            <div class="floating-div">Float 1</div>
            <div class="floating-div">Float 2</div>
            <div class="floating-div">Float 3</div>
            <div class="floating-div">Float 4</div>
            <div class="floating-div">Float 5</div>
            <div class="floating-div">Float 6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.clearfix { width: 30%; height: 100px; border: 1px solid}
.outer-div { position: relative; float: right; right: 50%; }
.inner-div { position: relative; float: right; right: -50%; }
.floating-div {  float: left; margin: 10px; border: 1px solid red; }
```

Increase and decrease browser zoom in order to see an effect. There are no necessary result now.
http://jsfiddle.net/TYK3J/4/

Comment: Please provide a demo of what you have tried so far.

Comment: have you perhaps set the `max-width` css property, thus limiting how far your divs can expand? Also, yeah, a jsfiddle would be nice.

Comment: instead of float use `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be a few ways to achieve this, but one possible way to target this is to have a media query for the elements container based on device dimensions. then when the media query triggers you could then style the container to align all of the div's center using something like text-align: center; for this case.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
  width: 615px;
}

.square{
  display: inline-block;
  background: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 716px) {
    .container{
      width: 995px;
      text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Working Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/K7SWAKj4wdjpeLaTwH4e?p=preview

Comment: There are always 3 squares in line. But it is necessary to have 3 squares in line on a small display, and 4 squares in first line, 2 in the second line on a big display (as shown on post shema by *).

Comment: I've updated the working example to accommodate for your request of small screen having 3 always and larger than a certain size making the  top row have 4 with children centered and having two. you would need to edit the widths and add max-width based on your specific requirements but hopefully this helps you. - http://plnkr.co/edit/K7SWAKj4wdjpeLaTwH4e?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to use some kind of wrapper around the 3 divs that you want to stay inline. Something like `.row` in [bootstrap css](http://getbootstrap.com/).

**CSS example**

```
.wrapper { width: 100%;}
.wrapper > div {
    width: 32%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/michasko/6yVQL/

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via floating, as the intention of floating is only to align elements left and right, originally inside inline text blocks.

The most common approach nowadays would be to use the `display: inline-block` attribute on the boxes and align them via `text-align: center` in the container. This solution needs some tricks to stay pixel-perfect. 
To have the boxes fill out the whole space you can use different CSS media queries to change the number of boxes in a row by dividing the space available (say, 25% width per box to have four of them in a single row up from 720px).

I propose you setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and try this solution – we can help you there, if you need more tips.

Addendum: The bleeding-edge solution would be to use flexboxes; these are still pretty uncommon along web developers though, as browser support is only recently getting better.

Addendum 2: I just saw that you tagged your post width javascript also; I wouldn't advise this solution, though there exist some formerly popular libs like [masonry](https://github.com/desandro/masonry) that allow for complex grid layouts.